# In math exams, how rigorous should the questions be?

Tags: undergraduate-education, exams, student-question

We have theoretical questions in our exams (often in ABCD format).
For example, I can state the question:

> For an indefinite integral, does it hold that $\int  f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx  = \int f(x)  dx $?

or should I state the question:

> Let $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two strictly
> monotonic differentiable functions with continuous derivatives. Does
> it hold that $\int  f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, dx  = \int f(x)  dx $?

Surely the 2nd one is more correct.
But it gets even worse with 2-variable calculus, where one often has to put a bunch of conditions on the most basic theorems. I feel that exams get bloated with conditions, but on the other hand, we should make the questions precise if we grade them. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Why are you choosing those conditions in the second statement?  It is false both ways, and adding/removing conditions does not change the fact that it is false.  If you changed the integrals to definite integrals (from $a$ to $b$ and $g(a)$ to $g(b)$ respectively) it would be true as long as $f$ is continuous and $g$ is continuously differentiable, with no monotonicity assumptions.

Comment: If multiple choice questions (I'm guessing this is what you mean by "ABCD format"), then you could simply ask something like the following: "Given suitable assumptions on the functions $f$ and $g,$ which of the following equalities holds?" Incidentally, I don't see any reason you need to write the words "indefinite integral". In fact, your wording might not be technically correct since there are two indefinite integrals that follow "For an indefinite integral", unless by "indefinite integral" the reference is to the operation itself, in which case it should be "For the indefinite integral".

Comment: For an high school or undergrad class, I'd be pretty happy if the student was able to point out that an otherwise true theorem was false due to missing assumptions. Assuming that they had a counterexample or something, and it wasnt just a drive-by 'false'. That would demonstrate plenty of subject matter understanding. (However, as @StevenGubkin said, there is something wrong with the theorem as stated.)

Comment: Also, too many conditions obscure the content of the theorem and can confuse students who, otherwise, have a decent working knowledge of what is going on.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: For exams given by individual teachers (which I assume is what the OP means), or even exams given by an entire department (e.g. a department's [common exam](https://www.math.tamu.edu/courses/math151/common-exams/) for a course), I don't think one needs to be so overly careful, as surely the context of the course topics and past exam questions (and 10-minute class quizzes, homework, lectures, etc.) suffice and can be defended against nit-picker students. Or ask the question for two specific functions such that the identity is true and each of the distractors is false.

Comment: Yes, be rigorous. If you're sloppy, how are you going to teach the students to be rigorous? Also, I agree with JochenGlueck and StevenGubkin. If I was a student and I was faced with a question like your indefinite integral, and asked simply for true or false, I wouldn't be able to answer, because I wouldn't be able to mindread the teacher and guess what unspoken assumptions they had and what the integral bounds were on this indefinite integral. In general, if the students need mindreading to understand the exam questions, then the exam questions are bad.

Comment: To make a reframing objection: I think this kind of question (not to mention the tortuousness of multiple-choice...) needlessly combines three reasonable issues in a way that creates confusion. First, sure, the chain rule for derivatives is good. Second, the fundamental theorem of calculus. Third, changing variables in a definite integral...

Comment: @StevenGubkin: why is the statement false? OK, maybe this wasn't the best example, but still, if we have short quizzes to tets of students know basic formulas, such as the divergence theorem, formally I should state that the vector field is "continuously differentiable on a neighborhood of the body", etc., I agree that this belongs to lectures, but also quizes?

Comment: @JakeB. This indicates, I think, a major lack of calculus knowledge on your part.  Try $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)  = 2x$ for example.  $\int f(g(x))g'(x) dx = \int 4x dx = 2x^2 + C$.  $\int f(x) dx = \int x dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C$.  These indefinite integrals are not equal.  I am concerned about your ability to teach a calculus class.  The theorem you are trying to quote only applies to definite integrals.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Ooooh! Yes, I completely blanked on the lack of $f'$ on the left-hand side of the putative equation!!!!????!!! Still, probably a typo? A nasty/pointless typo to have in an exam, for sure.

Comment: @paulgarrett worse than that.  Look again.  Theorem is fine for definite integrals, just plain old wrong for indefinite integrals.  In my example, try evaluating from x = 1 to x=2 in first integral and x = 1 to x=4 in second.  Works out fine.  Worse yet:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575498/should-substitution-in-indefinite-integral-be-monotone

Comment: This might be a "Code of Conduct" violation but I do not care.  I quit my job because I cannot suffer fools trying to be teachers anymore.  Teaching future elementary school teachers who cannot add fractions was intolerable.  Students deserve teachers who know what they are doing.  They deserve calculus teachers who understand the difference between a definite integral and an indefinite integral.  @JakeB. : Do better.

Comment: @StevenGubkin, Oof. Sigh. Indeed, we really do want to minimize the "noise" that students have to filter through... Sure, perfection is not possible, but there very real issues of "degree". Dang. :)

Comment: What exactly is "ABCD format"?

Answer (score 12):

On the one hand, the assumptions *are* an indispensable part of any theorem and many mistakes (well beyond the student homework) have been made exactly because somebody didn't understand that the conclusion of a certain result holds only under certain conditions which might be well-hidden in the sentences "assuming that $f$, $g$ are as in Lemma 5". So remembering formulae without clear understanding what classes of functions they can be applied to is not enough.

On the other hand, a lot of times we start teaching results in simple situations that are very far from full generality in which they really hold, so it is important to emphasize that some conditions are imposed just because of the students' limited knowledge, not because they are really needed.

The best practice is to bite a bit from both ends, i.e., to state and prove the theorem under assumptions that are easy to understand and check, but to show some really pathological counterexamples too so that the students would know that without assuming anything at all things can go awry.

If it were a decent analysis course, I would phrase your particular test question as follows.

Assuming that $f$ and $g$ are defined on the entire real line, $g$ is non-decreasing, and $a,b\in\mathbb R$, the change of variable formula
$$
\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(y)dy
$$
holds for the Riemann integral

A) For arbitrary locally Riemann integrable $f$ and differentiable $g$

B) For arbitrary continuous $f$ and continuously differentiable $g$

C) For arbitrary locally Riemann integrable $f$ and differentiable $g$ with locally Riemann integrable derivative.

D) For arbitrary locally Riemann integrable $f$ and continuously differentiable $g$

Choose the most general option that is correct.

In calculus you, probably, do not want to go that far, but you can make a similar list with options that are more obviously true or false.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that I am not sure whether $(C)$ is correct.  I cannot think of a counterexample, but a proof seems tough.  My usual tricks for proving different variants of this theorem are not strong enough.  Care to enlighten me?

Comment: @StevenGubkin Note that I imposed the condition that $g$ is non-decreasing, so $g'$ is non-negative. Now, $f$ (as a Riemann integrable function) can be squeezed between two piecewise constant functions with almost the same Riemann integral, so it is enough to check that both sides make sense and are equal when $f$ is a characteristic function of an interval. I'll let you take it from there :-)

Comment: Oh, I missed your non-decreasing condition.  I can certainly prove it in this case.  Do you have a proof or counterexample of (C) without this condition?

Comment: Too difficult. Probably in the lecture some theorem was shown, but not the most general one. The test shd check that the student can see why if one of the conditions is dropped (not just weakened) it wouldnt work anymore. Especially if time allocated for multiple choice is tight (usually less than 2 Minutes, often less than 1minute)

Comment: @StevenGubkin The existence of the LHS is not hard if you use heavier tools. The function $f(g)g'$ is bounded and continuous at every point where $g'$ is $0$ and continuous, and almost everywhere on a short interval around a point where $g'\ne 0$ and is continuous, so $f(g)g'$ is Riemann integrable. After that proving the equality should not be a big deal but I haven't tried to look at it yet. I'll see if I can find a simple reason for it in the evening; have some other fish to fry now :-)

Comment: @lalala I would give students 1-2 minutes per question *only if* what is asked should be nearly at the level of a knee reflex. Of course, what I wrote takes 5-10 minutes to comprehend fully for a decent student even if he/she knows everything. However, as I said, it is just a template. The actual question list should be of the same clarity, but tailored to the requirements of the course in question, which I don't know :-)

Comment: @fedja I posted an MSE question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759152/34287